# Python: Why is the multiprocessing lock shared among processes here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, multiprocessing, shared-variable

I am trying to share a lock among processes. I understand that the way to share a lock is to pass it as an argument to the target function. However I found that even the approach below is working. I could not understand the way the processes are sharing this lock. Could anyone please explain?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class SampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = mp.Lock()
        self.jobs = []
        self.total_jobs = 10

    def test_run(self):
        for i in range(self.total_jobs):
            p = mp.Process(target=self.run_job, args=(i,))
            p.start()
            self.jobs.append(p)

        for p in self.jobs:
            p.join()

    def run_job(self, i):
        with self.lock:
            print('Sleeping in process {}'.format(i))
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = SampleClass()
    t.test_run()
```

Comment: Perhaps you are on a Unix system.
 Read about [fork](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Comment: @JamesKPolk I am using Windows, Python 3.5.

Comment: What makes you think they are sharing the lock? If you delete the with self.lock line, do you get the same output?

Comment: What if mp.lock() is implemented as @staticmethod ?  You didn't create any object for multiprocessing class.

Comment: @HughFisher If I remove the self.lock line, every process gets started immediately and wait five seconds before completion. This is not the case when lock is there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows (which you said you're using), these kinds of things always reduce to details about how `multiprocessing` plays with `pickle`, because all Python data crossing process boundaries on Windows is implemented by pickling on the sending end (and unpickling on the receiving end).

My best advice is to avoid doing things that raise such questions to begin with ;-)  For example, the code you showed blows up on Windows under Python 2, and also blows up under Python 3 if you use a `multiprocessing.Pool` method instead of `multiprocessing.Process`.

It's not just the lock, simply trying to pickle a bound method (like `self.run_job`) blows up in Python 2.  Think about it.  You're crossing a process boundary, and there *isn't* an object corresponding to `self` on the receiving end.  To what object is `self.run_job` supposed to be bound on the receiving end?

In Python 3, pickling `self.run_job` *also* pickles a copy of the `self` object.  So that's the answer:  a `SampleClass` object corresponding to `self` is created by magic on the receiving end.  Clear as mud.  `t`'s entire state is pickled, including `t.lock`.  That's why it "works".

See this for more implementation details:

[Why can I pass an instance method to multiprocessing.Process, but not a multiprocessing.Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318290/why-can-i-pass-an-instance-method-to-multiprocessing-process-but-not-a-multipro)

In the long run, you'll suffer the fewest mysteries if you stick to things that were obviously intended to work:  pass module-global callable objects (neither, e.g., instance methods nor local functions), and explicitly pass `multiprocessing` data objects (whether an instance of `Lock`, `Queue`, `manager.list`, etc etc).

Answer (score 4):

On Unix Operating Systems, new processes are created via the [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) primitive.

The `fork` primitive works by cloning the parent process memory address space assigning it to the child. The child will have a copy of the parent's memory as well as for the file descriptors and shared objects.

This means that, when you call fork, if the parent has a file opened, the child will have it too. The same applied with shared objects such as pipes, sockets etc...

In Unix+CPython, `Locks` are realized via the `sem_open` primitive which is designed to be [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129845/why-does-sem-open-work-with-fork-without-shared-memory) when forking a process.

I usually recommend against mixing concurrency (multiprocessing in particular) and OOP because it frequently leads to these kind of misunderstandings.

EDIT:

Saw just now that you are using Windows. [Tim Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters) gave the right answer. For the sake of abstraction, Python is trying to provide OS independent behaviour over its API. When calling an instance method, it will pickle the object and send it over a pipe. Thus providing a similar behaviour as for Unix.

I'd recommend you to read the [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) for multiprocessing. Your issue is addressed in particular in the first point:

> Avoid shared state
>
> As far as possible one should try to avoid shifting large amounts of data between processes.
>
> It is probably best to stick to using queues or pipes for communication between processes rather than using the lower level synchronization primitives.